# Stock number in a list

Tags: python, list, function, sum

I did a code who gives me all combinaisons of addition between number .
For example, I have a list of 6 numbers and I have a function who gives me all the result possible between number to got my final number.

Here an example :

```
my final number : 15

My list:[2,4,6,7,9,11]


And to get 15 I have  4+11=15   or  9+6=15
```

But me I would like that I can stock my first result to use it later.

For example :

```
My list=[2,4,6,7,9,11]

My final number : 30

And to get 30, I got with my function  9+11+6+4=30

But I would  like to know How I can for example have this :

9+11=20
6+4=10
20+10=30

Here I stock 2 results and I add them together to get 30.
```

So I wouldlike know How I can stock result of addition to add them together after.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Please help us with your code so we can help you. You might be getting answers otherwise, but that won't resemble or match in any way with your code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). I won't say it's the optimized solution but it will give you the right answer.

Try this:

```
import itertools

li = [2,4,6,7,9,11]

def get_subset(li, total):
    for r in range(1, len(li) + 1):
        for sub in itertools.combinations(li, r):
            if sum(sub) == total:
                return sub

print(get_subset(li, 30))
print(get_subset(li, 15))
```

Output:

```
(4, 6, 9, 11)
(4, 11)
```